# How can I run cython'd shared libraries on Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cython

As the title says, I was wondering if Google Cloud Functions (where I currently have some pure python code) support cython'd modules?

I guess, more specifically, I'm asking about how I would use said modules? It's a private project, I'm using cython via setup.py and `cythonize(files)` which creates a bunch of shared object modules (`example.cpython-38-darwin.so`, `example1.cpython-38-darwin.so`, `example2.cpython-38-darwin.so`).

Those are all for Mac, so won't work on Firebase.

Is there any way to get Cloud Functions to run the setup.py and compile some files? Or, better yet, is there some way to pre-compile those files for the appropriate OS and just deploy the shared libs?

I know a variety of libraries I'm installing via `pip` on Cloud Functions use Cython under the hood, but I don't really know the process of creating a wheel or other pip dependency...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have been able to (eventually) solve this... I might have several unnecessary steps, but I think they improve my overall build system (again, with the intention of being able to use cython'd shared libraries on Firebase).

From Docker (or in my case, a Linux VM), in my private repo, I `cythonize` the important code, and turn everything into a wheel. From here, I run `auditwheel show` over the wheel, to check if it adheres to the `manylinux1` tag (or whichever `manylinux` I want). In this case, it did adhere to `manylinux1` off the bat, so there was no need to repair the wheel or do any shenanigans this time.

```sh
... .py # Other irrelevant .py files
magic.py # Source code that needs to be cython'd
setup.py
```

Simplified setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='magiclib',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        "magic.py",
        compiler_directives={'language_level': 3}
    )
)
```

Running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` creates a wheel named `dist/magiclib-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`

From here, I run `auditwheel show dist/magiclib-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl` which shows me that the code already adheres to the `manylinux1` tag, but I nonetheless run `auditwheel repair dist/magiclib-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl` which creates `wheelhouse/magiclib-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`.

At this point, I bring this wheel into my GCF project, and use:
`pip install -t magiclib magiclib-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

which basically unzips the wheel into a sub-directory that I can vendor and deploy to Google Cloud and call from my Functions.

Works fine on some of my simple code, and I'll be experimenting with some more involved code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `cython` as a build-time dependency for your private project by adding a `pyproject.toml` file like:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["cython"]
```

Then when installing your package with the modern version of `pip` in the Cloud Functions runtime, `cython` will be installed into the build environment before your `setup.py` script is run.

Comment: So, just some clarity on this... I can't upload pre-cython'd files, but I can have Google Cloud perform the build process on a private project? This makes it seem like I need to have them installed locally, and then upload them: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies

Comment: The installer, pip, is what handles installing build-time dependencies and then using them to build regular dependencies. This is a standard across the Python ecosystem, not just for Cloud Functions, see [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/).

Comment: You can also attempt to pre-build your dependency and have that installed instead, but that would require a) building the distributions on an identical platform to the Cloud Functions runtime, b) hosting the built distributions somewhere external but publicly accessible that Cloud Functions can access them c) modifying your `requirements.txt` file to point to these dependencies instead. It's a lot more work.

Comment: By "private project", what do you mean exactly? This is a source distribution hosted externally? A module used by your Cloud Function? There's lots of possibilities here, including some example code would help.

Comment: "Private" meaning not open-source to the world. Owned by my client, but I do have access to said source. In an ideal world, the files would be compiled by cython beforehand (by building on an identical platform to the Cloud Functions runtime), and just uploading the shared libs when I deploy my cloud function.

Comment: The earlier comment I made provided a link to GCloud's recommendations to vendor private dependencies and then upload them, the confusing part to me was that, if my vendored dependencies were compiled using cython (as opposed to being pure python files), then I would need to be running on the same OS as Cloud Functions (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#using_private_dependencies)... Unless I can `pip install` a local, vendored dependency - which seems to be a reasonable alternative for the moment.